# How to detect checked checkbox in other pages of datatables pagination using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatables

I have been using datatables for my project and only I discovered recently that the javascript I used is only selecting the checkboxes in the current page. Values of checked checkbox in other pagination/page is not selected or retrieved. Is there a way I can recognize checked checkboxes in all page of a pagination? Please help. Here is my code.

```
$('#create-po').click(function(e){     
    e.preventDefault();

     $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(i){
       valArray[i] = $(this).val();
     });

 });
```

This code recognizes checked checkboxes in a current page but not recognizes checked checkboxes in other page.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason you cannot use an extension on my original answer, you can instead watch for `change` events on the checkboxes and record them to an array accessible to your submit function later on.

Try checking a checkbox and click `x` to remove it from DOM and fire up `Create PO`. Their values should still be recorded.

```js
var $detached = [];
var $table = $('#dataTable');
var $valuesContainer = $('.selectValues');
var $countContainer = $('.selectCount');
var valArray = [];

// watch for change events on the checkbox
$("input:checkbox").on('change', function () {

  var value = $(this).val();

  if(this.checked) {
      valArray.push(value); // record the value of the checkbox to valArray
  } else {
      valArray.pop(value); // remove the recorded value of the checkbox
  }

});

// here do something to valArray
$('#create-po').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $valuesContainer.html(valArray.join(', '));  
    $countContainer.html(valArray.length);
})

// for testing purpose
$table.find('button').on('click', function () {
    var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
    $detached.push($row.detach());
});

$('#reset').on('click', function () {
    $table.find('tbody').append($detached);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><button id="reset">Reattach Removed Items</button></p>
<pre>
count: <span class="selectCount"></span>
values: [ <span class="selectValues"></span> ]
</pre>
<table id="dataTable">
  <tbody>
      <tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" value="item-1">item 1</label> <button>x</button></td></tr>
      <tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" value="item-2">item 2</label> <button>x</button></td></tr>
      <tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" value="item-3">item 3</label> <button>x</button></td></tr>
      <tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" value="item-4">item 4</label> <button>x</button></td></tr>
      <tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" value="item-5">item 5</label> <button>x</button></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p><a href="#" id="create-po">Create PO</a></p>
```

---

#### Edit

From how I understand your code, you are only counting how many checked elements there are at the time of click, sadly datatables are "redrawn" as you navigate away from that page. You will need to store your "checked" values somewhere else or use the built-in select extension.

I have stumbled upon this request as well and did a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jubalm/pooe7gnr/) you might find useful.

```js
var json = {"data": [{"name": "Tiger Nixon", "position": "System Architect", "salary": "$320,800", "start_date": "2011/04/25", "office": "Edinburgh", "extn": "5421"}, {"name": "Garrett Winters", "position": "Accountant", "salary": "$170,750", "start_date": "2011/07/25", "office": "Tokyo", "extn": "8422"}, {"name": "Ashton Cox", "position": "Junior Technical Author", "salary": "$86,000", "start_date": "2009/01/12", "office": "San Francisco", "extn": "1562"}, {"name": "Cedric Kelly", "position": "Senior Javascript Developer", "salary": "$433,060", "start_date": "2012/03/29", "office": "Edinburgh", "extn": "6224"}, {"name": "Airi Satou", "position": "Accountant", "salary": "$162,700", "start_date": "2008/11/28", "office": "Tokyo", "extn": "5407"}, {"name": "Brielle Williamson", "position": "Integration Specialist", "salary": "$372,000", "start_date": "2012/12/02", "office": "New York", "extn": "4804"}, {"name": "Herrod Chandler", "position": "Sales Assistant", "salary": "$137,500", "start_date": "2012/08/06", "office": "San Francisco", "extn": "9608"}, {"name": "Rhona Davidson", "position": "Integration Specialist", "salary": "$327,900", "start_date": "2010/10/14", "office": "Tokyo", "extn": "6200"}, {"name": "Colleen Hurst", "position": "Javascript Developer", "salary": "$205,500", "start_date": "2009/09/15", "office": "San Francisco", "extn": "2360"}, {"name": "Sonya Frost", "position": "Software Engineer", "salary": "$103,600", "start_date": "2008/12/13", "office": "Edinburgh", "extn": "1667"}, {"name": "Jena Gaines", "position": "Office Manager", "salary": "$90,560", "start_date": "2008/12/19", "office": "London", "extn": "3814"}, {"name": "Quinn Flynn", "position": "Support Lead", "salary": "$342,000", "start_date": "2013/03/03", "office": "Edinburgh", "extn": "9497"}, {"name": "Charde Marshall", "position": "Regional Director", "salary": "$470,600", "start_date": "2008/10/16", "office": "San Francisco", "extn": "6741"}, {"name": "Haley Kennedy", "position": "Senior Marketing Designer", "salary": "$313,500", "start_date": "2012/12/18", "office": "London", "extn": "3597"}, {"name": "Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "position": "Regional Director", "salary": "$385,750", "start_date": "2010/03/17", "office": "London", "extn": "1965"}, {"name": "Michael Silva", "position": "Marketing Designer", "salary": "$198,500", "start_date": "2012/11/27", "office": "London", "extn": "1581"}, {"name": "Paul Byrd", "position": "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "salary": "$725,000", "start_date": "2010/06/09", "office": "New York", "extn": "3059"}, {"name": "Gloria Little", "position": "Systems Administrator", "salary": "$237,500", "start_date": "2009/04/10", "office": "New York", "extn": "1721"}, {"name": "Bradley Greer", "position": "Software Engineer", "salary": "$132,000", "start_date": "2012/10/13", "office": "London", "extn": "2558"}, {"name": "Dai Rios", "position": "Personnel Lead", "salary": "$217,500", "start_date": "2012/09/26", "office": "Edinburgh", "extn": "2290"}, {"name": "Jenette Caldwell", "position": "Development Lead", "salary": "$345,000", "start_date": "2011/09/03", "office": "New York", "extn": "1937"}, {"name": "Yuri Berry", "position": "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "salary": "$675,000", "start_date": "2009/06/25", "office": "New York", "extn": "6154"}, {"name": "Caesar Vance", "position": "Pre-Sales Support", "salary": "$106,450", "start_date": "2011/12/12", "office": "New York", "extn": "8330"}, {"name": "Doris Wilder", "position": "Sales Assistant", "salary": "$85,600", "start_date": "2010/09/20", "office": "Sidney", "extn": "3023"}, {"name": "Angelica Ramos", "position": "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "salary": "$1,200,000", "start_date": "2009/10/09", "office": "London", "extn": "5797"}, {"name": "Gavin Joyce", "position": "Developer", "salary": "$92,575", "start_date": "2010/12/22", "office": "Edinburgh", "extn": "8822"}, {"name": "Jennifer Chang", "position": "Regional Director", "salary": "$357,650", "start_date": "2010/11/14", "office": "Singapore", "extn": "9239"}, {"name": "Brenden Wagner", "position": "Software Engineer", "salary": "$206,850", "start_date": "2011/06/07", "office": "San Francisco", "extn": "1314"}, {"name": "Fiona Green", "position": "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "salary": "$850,000", "start_date": "2010/03/11", "office": "San Francisco", "extn": "2947"}, {"name": "Shou Itou", "position": "Regional Marketing", "salary": "$163,000", "start_date": "2011/08/14", "office": "Tokyo", "extn": "8899"}, {"name": "Michelle House", "position": "Integration Specialist", "salary": "$95,400", "start_date": "2011/06/02", "office": "Sidney", "extn": "2769"}, {"name": "Suki Burks", "position": "Developer", "salary": "$114,500", "start_date": "2009/10/22", "office": "London", "extn": "6832"}, {"name": "Prescott Bartlett", "position": "Technical Author", "salary": "$145,000", "start_date": "2011/05/07", "office": "London", "extn": "3606"}, {"name": "Gavin Cortez", "position": "Team Leader", "salary": "$235,500", "start_date": "2008/10/26", "office": "San Francisco", "extn": "2860"}, {"name": "Martena Mccray", "position": "Post-Sales support", "salary": "$324,050", "start_date": "2011/03/09", "office": "Edinburgh", "extn": "8240"}, {"name": "Unity Butler", "position": "Marketing Designer", "salary": "$85,675", "start_date": "2009/12/09", "office": "San Francisco", "extn": "5384"}, {"name": "Howard Hatfield", "position": "Office Manager", "salary": "$164,500", "start_date": "2008/12/16", "office": "San Francisco", "extn": "7031"}, {"name": "Hope Fuentes", "position": "Secretary", "salary": "$109,850", "start_date": "2010/02/12", "office": "San Francisco", "extn": "6318"}, {"name": "Vivian Harrell", "position": "Financial Controller", "salary": "$452,500", "start_date": "2009/02/14", "office": "San Francisco", "extn": "9422"}, {"name": "Timothy Mooney", "position": "Office Manager", "salary": "$136,200", "start_date": "2008/12/11", "office": "London", "extn": "7580"}, {"name": "Jackson Bradshaw", "position": "Director", "salary": "$645,750", "start_date": "2008/09/26", "office": "New York", "extn": "1042"}, {"name": "Olivia Liang", "position": "Support Engineer", "salary": "$234,500", "start_date": "2011/02/03", "office": "Singapore", "extn": "2120"}, {"name": "Bruno Nash", "position": "Software Engineer", "salary": "$163,500", "start_date": "2011/05/03", "office": "London", "extn": "6222"}, {"name": "Sakura Yamamoto", "position": "Support Engineer", "salary": "$139,575", "start_date": "2009/08/19", "office": "Tokyo", "extn": "9383"}, {"name": "Thor Walton", "position": "Developer", "salary": "$98,540", "start_date": "2013/08/11", "office": "New York", "extn": "8327"}, {"name": "Finn Camacho", "position": "Support Engineer", "salary": "$87,500", "start_date": "2009/07/07", "office": "San Francisco", "extn": "2927"}, {"name": "Serge Baldwin", "position": "Data Coordinator", "salary": "$138,575", "start_date": "2012/04/09", "office": "Singapore", "extn": "8352"}, {"name": "Zenaida Frank", "position": "Software Engineer", "salary": "$125,250", "start_date": "2010/01/04", "office": "New York", "extn": "7439"}, {"name": "Zorita Serrano", "position": "Software Engineer", "salary": "$115,000", "start_date": "2012/06/01", "office": "San Francisco", "extn": "4389"}, {"name": "Jennifer Acosta", "position": "Junior Javascript Developer", "salary": "$75,650", "start_date": "2013/02/01", "office": "Edinburgh", "extn": "3431"}, {"name": "Cara Stevens", "position": "Sales Assistant", "salary": "$145,600", "start_date": "2011/12/06", "office": "New York", "extn": "3990"}, {"name": "Hermione Butler", "position": "Regional Director", "salary": "$356,250", "start_date": "2011/03/21", "office": "London", "extn": "1016"}, {"name": "Lael Greer", "position": "Systems Administrator", "salary": "$103,500", "start_date": "2009/02/27", "office": "London", "extn": "6733"}, {"name": "Jonas Alexander", "position": "Developer", "salary": "$86,500", "start_date": "2010/07/14", "office": "San Francisco", "extn": "8196"}, {"name": "Shad Decker", "position": "Regional Director", "salary": "$183,000", "start_date": "2008/11/13", "office": "Edinburgh", "extn": "6373"}, {"name": "Michael Bruce", "position": "Javascript Developer", "salary": "$183,000", "start_date": "2011/06/27", "office": "Singapore", "extn": "5384"}, {"name": "Donna Snider", "position": "Customer Support", "salary": "$112,000", "start_date": "2011/01/25", "office": "New York", "extn": "4226"}] }

var example = $('#example').DataTable({
  data: json.data,
  select: {
      style: 'multi'
  },
  columns: [
    {"data": "name"}, 
    {"data": "position"}, 
    {"data": "office"}, 
    {"data": "extn"}, 
    {"data": "start_date"}, 
    {"data": "salary"}
  ]
});

// custom counter
var counter = $('#count > span');

function updateCounter(data) {
  counter.html(data.length);
}

example.on('select', function() {
  var data = example.rows({
    selected: true
  }).data();
  updateCounter(data)
});

example.on('deselect', function() {
  var data = example.rows({
    selected: true
  }).data();
  updateCounter(data)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h4 id="count"><span></span> items selected</h4>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: That works. You can also use the [Datatables .$() api method](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24()) to use jQuery selectors on the whole table instead of just the current page

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
var selectedRowIds = [];
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
    $('#myTable tbody tr:has(input:checkbox:checked)').each(function(){
        //Collecting the row values of the checked rows in an array.
        selectedRowIds.push($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: It is not working :( . Still getting the current page checked checkbox.

Comment: I think this code should work. In your case, might be some other reason for failure. Could you please update your code in jsfiddle to see more in detail.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible solution to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42013146/6688183). The issue with only being able to get the values of the check boxes on the current page comes from the use of DOM methods with DataTables. In order to access other values you must use access the table using:

```
dataTable.rows().nodes().to$().find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){}
```

See [here](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-add-a-checkbox-column/) for a working version of checkbox values being stored and sent to the server. Additionally, the DataTable [FAQs](https://datatables.net/faqs/index) provide some useful information on DOM interaction.

Answer (score 0):

> JQUERY 3.3.1

```
    var detached = [];
    var table = $('#employee-grid').DataTable();
    var valuesContainer = $('.selectValues');
    var countContainer = $('.selectCount');
    var valArray = [];

// watch for change events on the checkbox

//        $('#example').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
//            var row =  table.row($(this).closest('tr'));
//            table.cell({ row: row.index(), column: 0 } ).data( this.checked ? 1 : 0 )
//            row.invalidate().draw()
//        })

    $('#employee-grid').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {

        var value = $(this).val();
        alert(value);
        if(this.checked) {
            valArray.push(value);   // record the value of the checkbox to valArray
        } else {
            valArray.pop(value);    // remove the recorded value of the checkbox
        }

    });

// here do something to valArray
        $('#create-po').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            valuesContainer.html(valArray.join(', '));
            countContainer.html(valArray.length);
        })

// for testing purpose
        table.find('button').on('click', function () {
            var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
            detached.push($row.detach());
        });
```

> HTML

```
<pre>
count: <span class="selectCount"></span>
values: [ <span class="selectValues"></span> ]
</pre>
```